# How to set a value of a sparse matrix to 0 without discarding the index

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

so I have the following scenario for a sparse matrix $X$:

```
for k = 1 : long_loop
    X(indexA{k}) = stuff;
end
X(indexB) = 0;
```

where some indices in indexA{k} and indexB overlap. The situation is, if I set indexB to 0, then MATLAB throws out the indexes in indexB from the definition of X, and then when those indices come up again in the loop, they are reallocated, and it makes the loop run very very slowly. What I would like to do is to set the values X indexed by indexB to 0 without discarding the indices. I currently set it up by using

```
X(indexB) = eps;
```

but I don't think that's a great solution, since eps is going to be a source of error later.

Any way to set the values of a sparse matrix to 0 without discarding the index?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set `nzmax` when initialising the sparse?

Comment: Adding elements to sparse matrices incrementally will always be a bit slower than using a full matrix, never mind the occasional setting to zero. If *Daniel*'s approach is not enough, you should rather apply a different strategy and build your sparse matrix after the computations, or use a temporary sparse matrix as a map of sparse indices to reduced full indices.

Comment: Using a full matrix will not be an option because I need X very large (100000 x 100000). I tried setting nzmax initially but for some reason it isn't working. I wonder if calling the sparse index somehow negated nzmax... The problem with building the sparse matrix after computations is that I need to use the updated matrix values within the loop. It's a weakness of the algorithm.

Comment: As I said: You can always use `Xreduced(I(i,j))`, where `I` is a sparse matrix which converts the values `i,j` to linear indices in `Xreduced`, which you could build in advance. As of now your question is otherwise quite broad, as you don't give any details on your problem except: *Using sparse is too slow.*

Comment: Oh I see, so essentially setting up my own sparse matrix format thing. That could definitely work! Thanks! (What I meant before is that recreating a sparse matrix at each iteration is very slow, 1 second, compared to .01 seconds to do everything else but your idea is much better!)